# Word VBA / Macro run on server Application.Run, ASP.NET, DCOM

Tags: asp.net, vba, ms-word

I am not a coder but need a task done.

We have a website that builds a word doc file using ckeditor based on answers from clients.

This documents needs afterwards to be formatted (TA/TC functions of word) which cannot be done with ckeditor.

Therefore we have a VBA/ macro that needs to be run in MS word after the doc file is generated.

I want to automate this step and have the VBA/macro run, before the doc is send to client.

So from my understanding, you have to take the CKeditor doc, run the macro on the server, and store it in the current database..
**Possible or not?**

Comment: This is not an odd-jobs forum, nor is it a code-for-free forum. Please add what you have tried so far, and then explain what is not working as you expect it to. Remember to include [mcve], and check out [ask], as you would have seen in the [tour] if you had taken it.

Answer (score 0):

This *should not* be done server-side. Working with Office applications server-side is not supported - Office applications are end-user applications. They can easily appear to "hang" when used, due to waiting for user input.

More information about using Office on a server can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

**Possible**: theoretically, yes, but impossible for anyone to guarantee as the code and document content are unknown. But, theoretically, if it works on a desktop it can work when run on a server.

The more "correct" way to manipulate Office documents on a server is to work directly with the Office Open XML files, instead of opening them in the application interface. The file formats were designed for this scenario and execution is also much faster. I'm guessing, however, since TC and TA fields are mentioned that the macro also builds TOCs? If yes, then the document would also have to be opened in order to generate the TOC (update the field). Server-side, that would mean using Word Automation Services, which is part of SharePoint.